# Python script to extract new data from file since it was last read

Tags: python, parsing, extract

I am working on a python script to do the following:-

I would like to read a log file every ten mins and on each read, I would like to extract any added data to the file since it was last read (preferably without having to read the entire log file each time).  Example:-

At 09:00 I read the log file and the content is:-

```
1. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,507 Processing request 17897931 from status 7 to 13
2. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,508 Processing request 17897931 from status 13 to 17
3. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,508 Processing request d0fcb681 from status 7 to 13
4. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,509 Processing request d0fcb681 from status 13 to 17
5. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,509 Processing request 178819a1 from status 7 to 13
```

At 09:10 I read the log file again and now the content is:-

```
1. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,507 Processing request 17897931 from status 7 to 13
2. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,508 Processing request 17897931 from status 13 to 17
3. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,508 Processing request d0fcb681 from status 7 to 13
4. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,509 Processing request d0fcb681 from status 13 to 17
5. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,509 Processing request 178819a1 from status 7 to 13
6. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,510 Processing request 178819a1 from status 13 to 17
7. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,510 Processing request 17161df1 from status 7 to 13
8. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,511 Processing request 17161df1 from status 13 to 17
9. 2011-07-04 11:15:04,511 Processing request 182013e1 from status 7 to 9
```

How can my script extract the new lines (lines 6. to 9.)?

I have a shell script that is doing this task already by using the file's inode.  I am looking for a solution based on python.

My plan is to execute the script via crontab.

Do you guys have any idea how I can get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check size of file
2. wait until size changes
3. open file, seek to previous size
4. read

Example:

```
import os, time
size = os.stat(file).st_size
time.sleep(600)
fh = open(file)
fh.seek(size)
newData = fh.read()
```

This example will, from time to time, read a partial line if another process is writing to the log at the same time. I'll leave that solution as an exercise :)

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the response.  What does the 'time.sleep(600)' line does?  Does this mean that the script is always running and it wakes up every ten mins?  Can this not be driven by crontab?

Comment: Sleeps for 10 minutes. You could use a crontab instead, but then you would have to write the last known size out to a file so you know where to pick up the next time.